# How do I use integers and floats within an object correctly?

Tags: c++, floating-point, integer, dynamic-memory-allocation

So I'm trying to write a program that keeps track of various attributes of wineries that has the following attributes.

-Dynamically allocated memory

-Integers to keep track of the year the winery started

-Floats for the success rating and acres of land the vineyards take up.

-Functions to add, remove, display (by rating and by name), and save the winery data.

I've already written/debugged code to work with a similar program where all the attributes were cstrings, and this code is based off the same framework.

My problem is that the same code that works for dynamically allocated cstrings doesn't work with integers or floats and I'm getting conversion error messages from the compiler. I have a `list` class that contains `aWinery` and since I'm using private members to hide the data I have functions to pass from the client program into the `list` and into `aWinery`. The functions with the same types are identical so I only include one of each type here.

Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong? I don't know how I would return through the parameters if `aWinery`'s definition of the int and floats were not pointers. The only examples of dynamic memory programming I can find with classes use cstrings. I've noted a couple points in the code that I copied from an instructor because I couldn't figure it out.

EDIT: the specific error I'm getting is `invalid conversion from int* to int\n year = this->year` which some permutation of occurs in all of the `aWinery`'s integer and float based accessor and mutator functions.

List Accessor, Mutator, Constructor, and Destructor functions

```
void list::getWineryLocation(char location[]) const
{
    wineryData.getLocation(location);
}

void list::getWineryYear(int year) const
{
    wineryData.getYear(year);
}

void list::getWineryAcres(float acres) const
{
    wineryData.getAcres(acres);
}

void list::setWineryLocation(char location[])
{
    wineryData.setLocation(location);
}

void list::setWineryYear(int year)
{
    wineryData.setYear(year);
}

void list::setWineryAcres(float acres)
{
    wineryData.setAcres(acres);
}

//Constructor functions

list::list()
{
    nameHead = NULL;
    nameTail = NULL;
    ratingHead = NULL;
    ratingTail = NULL;
    size = 0;
}

//Destructor
//Doesn't delete the head/tailRating pointers to avoid double deleting a winery
list::~list()
{
    node * curr = nameHead;

    while (nameHead != NULL)
    {
        curr = nameHead->nextByName;

        delete nameHead;

        nameHead = curr;
    }
}
```

aWinery Accessor, Mutator, Constructor, and Destructor functions

```
//Winery object constructor
aWinery::aWinery()
{
    name = new char[strlen("Unknown")+1];
    strcpy(name, "Unknown");
    location = new char[strlen("Unknown")+1];
    strcpy(location, "Unknown");
    year = new int;
    year = 0;
    acres = new float;
    acres = 0;
    successRating = new float;
    successRating = 0;
}

//I have no idea whats going on here
//Winery destructor
aWinery::~aWinery()
{   
    if(name != NULL)
        delete [] name;
    if(location != NULL)
        delete [] location;
    if(year != 0)
        delete year;
    if(acres != 0)
        delete acres;
    if(successRating != 0)
        delete successRating;
}

void aWinery::getLocation(char location[]) const
{
    strcpy(location, this->location);
}

void aWinery::getYear(int year) const
{
    year = this->year;
}

void aWinery::getAcres(float acres) const
{
    acres = this->acres;
}

//I have no idea why this is written this way, I copied this from an instructor example
void aWinery::setLocation(char location0[])
{
    if(this->location != NULL)
        delete [] this->location;
    this->location =  new char[strlen(location0)+1];

    strcpy(this->location, location0);
}

void aWinery::setYear(int year0)
{
    if(this->year != 0)
        delete this->year;
    this->year =  new int;

    this->year = year0;
}

void aWinery::setAcres(float acres0)
{
    if(this->acres != 0)
        delete this->acres;
    this->acres =  new float;

    this->acres = acres0;
}
```

aWinery header file

```
#ifndef AWINERY_H
#define AWINERY_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//winery object
class aWinery
{
public:
    //Constructor
    aWinery();

    //Destructor
    ~aWinery();

    //Accessor Prototypes
    void getName(char name[]) const;
    void getLocation(char location[]) const;
    void getYear(int year) const;
    void getAcres(float acres) const;
    void getSuccessRating(float successRating) const;

    //Mutator Prototypes
    void setName(char name0[]);
    void setLocation(char location0[]);
    void setYear(int year0);
    void setAcres(float acres0);
    void setSuccessRating(float successRating0);


private:
    char* name;
    char* location;
    int* year;
    float* acres;
    float* successRating;
};

#endif
```

list header file

```
#ifndef ALIST_H
#define ALIST_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int MAX_CHAR_LENGTH = 1000;

class list
{
public:
    //Prototypes
    void setInWinery(char name[], char location[], int year, float acres, float successRating);
    void initializeDbase(char savePathName[]);
    void printEntireDbase();
    void deleteWinery(char nameOfWinery[]);
    void whereIsWinery(char nameOfWinery[]);
    void save(char savePathName[]);

    //Accessor Prototypes
    void getWineryName(char name[]) const;
    void getWineryLocation(char location[]) const;
    void getWineryYear(int year) const;
    void getWineryAcres(float acres) const;
    void getWinerySuccessRating(float successRating) const;
    int getSize() const;

    //Mutator Prototypes
    void setWineryName(char name[]);
    void setWineryLocation(char location[]);
    void setWineryYear(int year);
    void setWineryAcres(float acres);
    void setWinerySuccessRating(float successRating);

    //Constructor Prototype
    list();

    //Destructor
    ~list();

private:
    //Wine object
    struct node
    {
        aWinery wineryData;
        node * nextByName;
        node * nextByRating;
    };
    node * nameHead, * nameTail, * ratingHead, * ratingTail;

    aWinery wineryData;

    int size;
};

#endif
```

Comment: "Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong?" - perhaps the course?  Your instructor shouldn't be teaching you to allocation your own character arrays, use strlen/strcpy etc. - use `std::string`.  Better not to mix in list functionality with your data types - do one thing well and you can test and understand it independently, then reuse it.  `std::list` already does lists well.  Do not use `int*` and `float*` to store individual values: just store them directly by value.  Finally, for this site - ask *focused* questions on a specific technical issue, distilled to a short code example.

Comment: @TonyD If I had a dime for every time someone has told me the course/school/teacher is stupid. I would have a *lot* of dimes. They are obviously better but I don't have a choice in a lot of matters. I will ask smaller questions in the future, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the bulk of your problem is in the header, here:

```
private:  
   char* name;
   char* location;
   int* year;
   float* acres;
   float* successRating;
```

There's really no reason to use pointers for any of these member variables; you might as well make them all plain-old by-value members, like this:

```
private:  
   std::string name;
   std::string location;
   int year;
   float acres;
   float successRating;
```

Note that I replaced the (char *) member variables with std::string, since in a C++ program there's really no reason not to use a proper string object.  (Using dynamically allocated char arrays to hold character strings might be a necessary evil if you're writing in C, but in C++ it's just masochism)

By storing all of your data by-value, you can get rid of all of the `new` and `delete` commands (and the inevitable bugs and inefficiency that come with them) and just set and get the values directly when necessary.

Also, this accessor function is wrong:

```
void aWinery::getYear(int year) const
{
    year = this->year;
}
```

It won't work because in C++, method parameters are (by default) passed by value (i.e. a temporary local copy of the passed-in value is made, for the method to use), so all the above method does is modify the local parameter `year`, which is then immediately destroyed as soon as the function returns.  A proper accessor method would look more like this:

```
int aWinery::getYear() const
{
    return this->year;   // assuming year member variable is now of type int
}
```

.... and similarly, the setter method should look like this:

```
void aWinery::setYear(int newYear)
{
    this->year = newYear;   // assuming year member variable is now of type int
}
```